# Adding button to titlebar (like Firefox 4) in VB.NET & WPF or WinForms on XP or Vista/7

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, firefox, aero

I was wondering if it is possible to add a button to the title bar in vb.net - I found a way to do this in one or the other but is it possible to do it on both?

Here is the code that works if Aero is disabled (imports System.RunTime.InteropServices):

```
Private Const WM_NCPAINT As Integer = 133
Private Const WM_NCMOUSEMOVE As Integer = 160
Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Integer = 161
Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONUP As Integer = 162
Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK As Integer = 163
Private Const WM_NCACTIVATE As Integer = 134
Private Const WM_NCMOUSELEAVE As Integer = 674

Private TitleBarButtonRectangle As Rectangle
Private TitleBarButtonState As ButtonState
Private TitleBarMouseIsDown As Boolean

Private Enum ButtonState As Byte
    Normal
    Hot
    Pressed
End Enum




Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    'Process the non client area messages here.

    Select Case m.Msg

        Case WM_NCPAINT, WM_NCACTIVATE, WM_NCMOUSELEAVE
            'process the message and reset the <strong class="highlight">button</strong> to the normal state
            'and draw it. This will draw the initial <strong class="highlight">button</strong> and repaint it
            'if the title bar needs a paint update.
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
            TitleBarButtonState = ButtonState.Normal
            TitleBarMouseIsDown = False
            DrawButton(TitleBarButtonState)

        Case WM_NCMOUSEMOVE
            'The mouse is moving in the non client area.

            If TitleBarButtonRectangle.Contains(GetNonClientPoint(CInt(m.LParam))) Then
                'the mouse is in the <strong class="highlight">button</strong>
                'If the mouse is down then draw it pressed if not already
                'If the mouse is not down then draw it hot if not already
                If TitleBarMouseIsDown Then
                    If TitleBarButtonState <> ButtonState.Pressed Then
                        TitleBarButtonState = ButtonState.Pressed
                        DrawButton(TitleBarButtonState)
                    End If
                Else
                    If TitleBarButtonState <> ButtonState.Hot Then
                        TitleBarButtonState = ButtonState.Hot
                        DrawButton(TitleBarButtonState)
                    End If
                End If

            Else
                'The mouse is not in the <strong class="highlight">button</strong>.
                'If the mouse is down then draw it hot, when the
                'mouse moves back into the <strong class="highlight">button</strong> it will be redrawn pressed.

                'Otherwise draw it normal if its not already.
                If TitleBarMouseIsDown Then
                    If TitleBarButtonState <> ButtonState.Hot Then
                        TitleBarButtonState = ButtonState.Hot
                        DrawButton(TitleBarButtonState)
                    End If
                Else
                    If TitleBarButtonState <> ButtonState.Normal Then
                        TitleBarButtonState = ButtonState.Normal
                        DrawButton(TitleBarButtonState)
                    End If

                End If

            End If

            'When the mouse is down and it leaves the window 
            'it will remain in its hot or pressed state. when the
            'mouse is let up outside the window and moved it will 
            'recieve a message to repaint.

            'Process all the mouse moves.
            MyBase.WndProc(m)

        Case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN
            'Left mouse <strong class="highlight">button</strong> has been held down in the non client area

            'If the mouse is inside the <strong class="highlight">button</strong> then change its state to pressed
            'and redraw it.  Store that the mouse is down.
            If TitleBarButtonRectangle.Contains(GetNonClientPoint(CInt(m.LParam))) Then
                TitleBarButtonState = ButtonState.Pressed
                DrawButton(TitleBarButtonState)
                TitleBarMouseIsDown = True
            Else
                'process the message it was clicked somewhere in the non client
                'area but not in the <strong class="highlight">button</strong>.
                MyBase.WndProc(m)
            End If


        Case WM_NCLBUTTONUP
            'Mouse is being released in the non client area

            If TitleBarMouseIsDown AndAlso TitleBarButtonRectangle.Contains(GetNonClientPoint(CInt(m.LParam))) Then
                'The mouse was down and the mouse is in the <strong class="highlight">button</strong>.
                'It has been pressed.
                TitleBarButtonState = ButtonState.Hot
                DrawButton(TitleBarButtonState)
                MsgBox("The Titlebar button was clicked")

            Else
                'Process the message and reset the <strong class="highlight">button</strong> to normal if its not already.
                MyBase.WndProc(m)

                If TitleBarButtonState <> ButtonState.Normal Then
                    TitleBarButtonState = ButtonState.Normal
                    DrawButton(TitleBarButtonState)
                End If

            End If

            'Reset that the mouse is down
            TitleBarMouseIsDown = False

        Case WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK
            'Mouse has been double clicked in the non client area.

            'If the cursor is in the <strong class="highlight">button</strong> then don't process the double click
            'If processed the form will change window states.
            If Not TitleBarButtonRectangle.Contains(GetNonClientPoint(CInt(m.LParam))) Then
                MyBase.WndProc(m)
            End If

        Case Else

            'Process the regular messages
            MyBase.WndProc(m)

    End Select

End Sub

Private Function GetNonClientPoint(ByVal lParam As Integer) As Point
    'The lo word in the lparam is the x coordinate and the hi word is the y.
    'The coordinates are in screen coordinates so subtract the location of the
    'form to get the location <strong class="highlight">on</strong> the title bar.  This will have to be adjusted.
    'There will be issues <strong class="highlight">on</strong> mdi forms.
    Dim ScreenPoint As New Point(CInt(lParam And Short.MaxValue), CInt(lParam >> 16))
    Return ScreenPoint - CType(Me.Location, Size)
End Function

Private Sub DrawButton(ByVal buttonState As ButtonState)
    'Gets the graphics to the entire window.
    'Draws a visual style <strong class="highlight">button</strong>.
    'Draw your own graphics here.
    'If using the visual style renderer then you will need
    'any alternate drawing mode in case the renderer is not
    'supported.  ControlPaint will draw a <strong class="highlight">button</strong> without 
    'visual styles.

    Dim EntireWindowGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(GetWindowDC(Me.Handle))

    Dim StrFrmt As New StringFormat
    StrFrmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    StrFrmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    StrFrmt.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap
    StrFrmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter

    Select Case buttonState
        Case Form1.ButtonState.Normal
            If VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer.IsSupported Then
                Dim VisualRenderer As New VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton.Normal)
                VisualRenderer.DrawBackground(EntireWindowGraphics, TitleBarButtonRectangle)
            Else
                ControlPaint.DrawButton(EntireWindowGraphics, TitleBarButtonRectangle, Windows.Forms.ButtonState.Normal)
            End If

        Case Form1.ButtonState.Hot
            If VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer.IsSupported Then
                Dim VisualRenderer As New VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton.Hot)
                VisualRenderer.DrawBackground(EntireWindowGraphics, TitleBarButtonRectangle)
            Else
                ControlPaint.DrawButton(EntireWindowGraphics, TitleBarButtonRectangle, Windows.Forms.ButtonState.Normal)
            End If

        Case Form1.ButtonState.Pressed
            If VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer.IsSupported Then
                Dim VisualRenderer As New VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton.Pressed)
                VisualRenderer.DrawBackground(EntireWindowGraphics, TitleBarButtonRectangle)
            Else
                ControlPaint.DrawButton(EntireWindowGraphics, TitleBarButtonRectangle, Windows.Forms.ButtonState.Pushed)
            End If

    End Select

    EntireWindowGraphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit
    EntireWindowGraphics.DrawString("Click Me", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, TitleBarButtonRectangle, StrFrmt)
    EntireWindowGraphics.Dispose()
    StrFrmt.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub SizeButton()
    'This is hard coded for a sizable 3d window border.
    'Other properties of the systemInformation class can
    'adjust for fixed and single borders.
    'SystemInformation.BorderSize
    'SystemInformation.FixedFrameBorderSize

    'if the window is maximized then its sizing border will not be
    'displayed so the y is set to the bordersize and the height of the <strong class="highlight">button</strong>
    'is set to the caption height.  If its not maximized the y is set to
    '0 and the <strong class="highlight">button</strong> height is set to the caption height plus the border size.
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
        TitleBarButtonRectangle.Y = 0
        TitleBarButtonRectangle.Height = SystemInformation.CaptionHeight + SystemInformation.HorizontalResizeBorderThickness
    Else
        TitleBarButtonRectangle.Y = SystemInformation.HorizontalResizeBorderThickness
        TitleBarButtonRectangle.Height = SystemInformation.CaptionHeight
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    'Change the size of the <strong class="highlight">button</strong>.
    'May have been maximized or normalized
    SizeButton()
End Sub

'Gets the graphics to the entire window.
<DllImport("user32.dll")> Public Shared Function GetWindowDC(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    TitleBarButtonRectangle = New Rectangle(30, 0, 75, 25)

    SizeButton()

End Sub
```

But when Aero is disabled, the button doesn't appear, although it still fires an event if the area is clicked.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the task easily with the [WPF Shell Integration Library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell)

[image]