# Custom button in WPF window Titlebar

Tags: wpf, window, titlebar

I like to add a custom button in WPF Native Window title bar without editing the style of the Window.

Is it possible? If yes, please share some ideas.

Regards,

Jawahar

Comment: You can make your own Title Bar and not use the standard window outline/style. This describes it pretty well http://cloudstore.blogspot.com/2008/06/moving-wpf-window-with-windowstyle-of.html

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116553/adding-button-to-titlebar-like-firefox-4-in-vb-net-wpf-or-winforms-on-xp-or

Answer (score 1):

Mahapps is a UI toolkit for WPF and they make this super easy:
[mahapps.com](http://mahapps.com/)

Easy install using NuGet GUI or the Packet Manager console:

```
PM> Install-Package MahApps.Metro
```

I was able to do the install and customization in less than half hour with Mahapp.