# How to render buttons and such on window title bar in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am able to move a button onto the title bar using the margin and transform features of WPF. However, when I try it, the button is indeed on the titlebar, but it does not get clicks or mouse hovers because its out of the client area. If I double click on it, it just maximizes/restores the window, as if the window is the first one to get the events. Is there some way (without excessive tricks) to achieve what I tried to describe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding button to titlebar (like Firefox 4) in VB.NET & WPF or WinForms on XP or Vista/7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116553/adding-button-to-titlebar-like-firefox-4-in-vb-net-wpf-or-winforms-on-xp-or)

Answer (score 3):

Not long after I found out the way to  do this:

I downloaded http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell binaries, and added the dll as a reference.

I followed the sample source guides and realized that I needed to write e.g. `<TabControl shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">` to get the clicks and actions get through to my components :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you need but maybe it could be a possible direction:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80255/Add-Your-Control-On-Top-Another-Application